# perl script to read in a file and compare each line with previous line

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks like:

```
chr start end fold_enrichment  
1 760605 769233 15.65  
1 760605 769233 44.11  
1 760605 769233 18.5  
1 760605 769233 11.38  
1 947714 951356 110.99  
1 1404923 1410311 96.76  
1 1404923 1410311 27.04
```

I would like to write a perl script that goes through the file line by line and compares each line with the previous line (or next line) to look for matching values in the first 3 columns. Then I would like to print the values in the first three columns only once, with the fourth column value pushed on as new column.

For example, I want to take

```
1 760605 769233 15.65  
1 760605 769233 44.11  
1 760605 769233 18.5
```

and print

```
1 760605 769233 15.65 44.11 18.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free-of-charge coding service. We will help you fix your program if you are stuck, but please don't expect to be able to place orders for software here

Comment: apologies, first time asking a question

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -ape '$k="@F[0..2]"; $_=" $F[3]",next if $k eq $o; $_= "\n@F";$o=$k' file
```

output

```
1 760605 769233 15.65 44.11 18.5 11.38
1 947714 951356 110.99
1 1404923 1410311 96.76 27.04
```

Answer (score 1):

As Borodin said, SO is not intended as a free service.  Please always show your work and explain where you're having trouble.

However, yes, occasionally some of us will be more generous for the fun of it.  A perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -pe "1 while (s/^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+) (.*?)\s*\n\1 (.*)/$1 $2 $3/mg)" data.txt
```

Outputs:

```
chr start end fold_enrichment
1 760605 769233 15.65 44.11 18.5 11.38
1 947714 951356 110.99
1 1404923 1410311 96.76 27.04
```

Comment: noted, and thanks for the generosity

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at the one-liner:

```
perl -lane '$k="@F[0..2]"; push @o,$k if !$h{$k}; push @{$h{$k}},$F[3] }{ print "$_ @{$h{$_}}" for @o' file
```

**Output:**

```
chr start end fold_enrichment
1 760605 769233 15.65 44.11 18.5 11.38
1 947714 951356 110.99
1 1404923 1410311 96.76 27.04
```

**Explaination:**

- `-a` option splits the line into fields.
- `-l` option does the chomp for us and puts back the new line during printing
- `-n` option executes for each line of the file
- `-e` option tells perl to execute the code block
- `$k = "@F[0..2]"` creates a variable `$k` which holds the first three fields of the current line
- `push @o, $k if !$h{$k}` creates an array and pushes the variable to it only if it is not present in our hash. This is to prevent dups from being inserted. This is also done so that we can preserve the order
- `push @{$h{$k}}, $F[3]` we are creating hash of arrays. Pushing to a hash with key as `$k` and value as the last field.
- `}{` denotes the `END` block
- `print "$_ @{$h{$_}}" for @o` prints the key and the value for each element of our array `@o`.

**Here is the one liner in more readable form:**

```
perl -lane '{
    $k = "@F[0..2]";  
    push @o, $k if !$h{$k}; 
    push @{$h{$k}}, $F[3]
}
END { 
    print "$_ @{$h{$_}}" for @o
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks JS. Please bear with me, I'm new to coding. I understand up til !$h{$k}, can you tell me what this is doing?

Comment: @theo4786 Please check the revised answer.